# Angular Maps With Default Templates

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm creating a map component using [AngularMaps](https://angular-maps.com/)

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isCreating">
      <agm-marker color="Blue" *ngFor="let locationGroup of locationEntitiesMap" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(locationGroup)" 
        [latitude]="locationGroup?.location?.latitude" [longitude]="locationGroup?.location?.longitude">

        <agm-snazzy-info-window [maxWidth]="200" [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true">
            <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="options.template || defaultTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{group: locationGroup}">
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #defaultTemplate let-group="group">
              <div>XJ543sB</div>  
              <ng-container *ngFor="let data of group.data">
                  <ion-label>Location: </ion-label>
                  <ion-label>{{group.location.name}} </ion-label>
                  <ion-button (click)="selectLocation(group.location, data)">
                    {{options.selectLabel}}
                  </ion-button>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-template>
        </agm-snazzy-info-window>
      </agm-marker>
  </ng-container>
    <agm-marker *ngIf="isCreating" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [markerDraggable]="true"
      (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)">
    </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I checked the dom and I've verified that the template is actually being populated with the TemplateOutletContext, however it always renders blank for some reason

I've created a simplified version in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uimscl?file=src/app/app.component.html) here representing the problem, I'm trying to reference the default template using the [TemplateOutlet] but nothing renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create simple `ng-template` and then render inside whatever you want:

```
<my-info-window [offset]="offset">
  <ng-template>
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="defaultTemplate"></ng-template>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #defaultTemplate>
    Phoenix
  </ng-template>

</my-info-window>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4uy3jg?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me alot of time!